# Could Hilbert Spaces offer the vehicle to make Synergetic's IVM System Functional?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, coordinate-systems

This one is a bit out there in left field, and hope it doesn't draw too much flak.

Intended more for the "Mathematically Adept" out there ... which I am not.

Please understand that I am not a mathematician ... but after poking around, I wonder if there are some avenues that might offer more useful outcomes than others.  To that end, here goes ...

**Challenge:**
Is it possible to define an instantiation of
**Hilbert Space** as an embodiment of Fuller's
**Isotropic Vector Matrix System** ?

Is there anyone out there that knows enough about Hilbert Spaces to offer a "**rigorous but suitable for layman**" explanation of whether

- the non-orthogonal 4-vector space defined by Buckminster Fuller's
  Vector Equilibrium (Isotropic Vector Matrix System), where each
  vector can only be a +ve multiple of the directional unit vectors

could be mapped, using a Hilbert Space, such that a **2-way reversible mapping function** would be defined for transforming to and from that IVM Space and Cartesian Space?

I may have misunderstood the end-application of Hilbert Spaces, and may have put forward an unrealistic problem, or may have made an invalid association between Hilbert Spaces and the IVM System, but I felt it was worth a try putting that problem out there for consideration.

Thank you for taking the time to consider and to offer a "layman's" explanation as to its feasibility ... or lack thereof.

Eric
 *member of [Geodesic Help Group](https://groups.google.com/g/geodesichelp?hl=en)*